# How to write a program for 2 D curvilinear interpolation?

Tags: 2d

2-D curvilinear interpolation

Apply the tensorization for 2-D Lagrangian interpolation of order 4 on a sinusoidal grid given by:

% Definition of sinusoidal grid

% -----------------------------

nx=41;

ny=41;

xmin=0;

ymin=0;

xmax=80;

ymax=80;

lx=xmax-xmin;

ly=ymax-ymin;

facteur=1.;

ax=2*facteur;

ay=2*facteur;

enex=4;

eney=4;

phix=0;

phiy=0;

omegatau=0.25;

deltax0=lx/(nx-1);

deltay0=ly/(ny-1);

for i=1:nx,

for j=1:ny,

xg(i,j) = xmin+deltax0*((i-1)+ax*sin(2.0*pi*omegatau)...

sin(enex*pi(j-1)*deltay0/ly+i*phix/(nx-1)));

yg(i,j) = ymin+deltay0*((j-1)+ay*sin(2.0*pi*omegatau)...

sin(eney*pi(i-1)*deltax0/lx+j*phiy/(ny-1)));

val(i,j)=1;

end

end

% Definition of a 2D Gaussian function (test function)

% ------------------------------------

alph=log(2)/10^2; % width of Gaussian

i0=20; % center of Gaussian

j0=20; % center of Gaussian

for i=1:nx

for j=1:ny

U2(i,j)=exp(-alph*((xg(i,j)-xg(i0,j0))^2+(yg(i,j)-yg(i0,j0))^2));

end

end

% Interpolation on NxN points -> order N

% --------------------------------------

% order

N=4;

% width of interpolation per direction

dw=N;

% degrees of freedom

dl=dw*dw;

% interpolation point at (xint,yint)

% ----------------------------------

ii=23;

ji=23;

xint=xg(ii,ji)+1;

yint=yg(ii,ji)+1;

Then find the location of the point to be interpolated in the computational space using the isoparametric mapping and 2-D Newton’s algorithm.